# Splash screen not showing up in Cordova project

Tags: android, cordova

My Project build is made using cordova CLI. Have used **cordova version 4.0+**. The only problem is that the splash screen is not showing up. I have tested the application in android devices.

I have a  `config.xml` located in the root folder. When searched for answers, many answers are showing up in which, the config.xml is located inside www folder.

And my splash screens are located in
 `project_folder\platforms\android\res\drawable\filename.png`

Is this issue related to the path given? if not, what probably will be the error i have made?

Can someone help me out to solve this issue.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

the correct path should be `project_folder\platforms\android\res\drawable\filename.png`.

Answer (score 0):

config.xml should be outside www/ folder (in the root of your project)
Have you added the following preferences to config.xml? :

```
<preference name="SplashScreen" value="splash" />
<preference name="SplashScreenDelay" value="4000" />
```

Is the name specified in the 'value' option up there the same of your image placed in:

```
yourProjectName\platforms\android\res\drawable
```

?